# How to extract a link with Jsoup?

Tags: java, web-crawler, jsoup

I am using JSoup to crawl the web and get results. I want to perform a keyword search. For example I crawl
http://www.business-standard.com/ for the following keywords:

> google hyderabad

and it should provide me with the link:

> http://www.business-standard.com/article/companies/google-to-get-7-2-acres-in-hyderabad-it-corridor-for-its-campus-115051201238_1.html.

I wrote the code below which did not give me appropriate results.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Document doc;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.business-standard.com").userAgent("Mozilla").get();
        String title = doc.title();
        System.out.println("title : " + title);

        Elements links = doc.select("a:contains(google)");
        for (Element link : links) {
            System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
            System.out.println("text : " + link.text());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

The results are as follows:

```
title : India News, Latest News Headlines, BSE live, NSE Live, Stock Markets Live, Financial News, Business News & Market Analysis on Indian Economy - Business Standard News

link : /photo-gallery/current-affairs/mumbai-central-turns-into-wi-fi-zone-courtesy-goo‌​gle-power-2574.htm
text : Mumbai Central turns into Wi-Fi zone, courtesy Google power

link : plus.google.com/+businessstandard/posts
text : Google+
```

**Jsoup 1.8.2**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Google crawls the web and indexes what it crawls as two separate processes.

Comment: What do you mean by not getting appropriate results? Any non-allowed 4-letter words?

Comment: The results are as follows:- **title : India News, Latest News Headlines, BSE live, NSE Live, Stock Markets Live, Financial News, Business News & Market Analysis on Indian Economy - Business Standard News

link : /photo-gallery/current-affairs/mumbai-central-turns-into-wi-fi-zone-courtesy-google-power-2574.htm
text : Mumbai Central turns into Wi-Fi zone, courtesy Google power

link : https://plus.google.com/+businessstandard/posts
text : Google+**

Comment: You need to define a rule for determining what a 'keyword' is. Then you need to index those usages, and your search needs to feed off that dataset. JSoup is only going to be a tiny part (at best) of that larger solution.

Comment: @AndrewRegan, thanks. Can you help with a sample code or direct a link,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this url instead:

```
http://www.business-standard.com/search?q=<keyword>
```

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
Document doc;
try {
    String keyword = "google hyderabad";
    doc = Jsoup //
            .connect("http://www.business-standard.com/search?q=" + URLEncoder.encode(keyword, "UTF-8")) //
            .userAgent("Mozilla") //
            .get();

    String title = doc.title();
    System.out.println("title : " + title);

    Elements links = doc.select("a:contains(google)");
    for (Element link : links) {
        System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.absUrl("href"));
        System.out.println("text : " + link.text());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

#### OUTPUT

The link you're looking for is in second position.

```
title : Search

link : http://www.business-standard.com/article/pti-stories/google-to-invest-more-in-india-set-up-new-campus-115121600841_1.html
text : Google to invest more in India, set up new campus in Hyderabad

link : http://www.business-standard.com/article/companies/google-to-get-7-2-acres-in-hyderabad-it-corridor-for-its-campus-115051201238_1.html
text : Google to get 7.2 acres in Hyderabad IT corridor for its campus

link : http://www.business-standard.com/article/technology/swine-flu-closes-google-hyderabad-office-for-2-days-109071500023_1.html
text : Swine flu closes Google Hyderabad office for 2 days

link : http://www.business-standard.com/article/pti-stories/facebook-posts-strong-4q-as-company-closes-gap-with-google-116012800081_1.html
text : Facebook posts strong 4Q as company closes gap with Google

link : http://www.business-standard.com/article/pti-stories/r-day-bsf-camel-contingent-march-on-google-doodle-116012600104_1.html
text : R-Day: BSF camel contingent marches on Google doodle

link : http://www.business-standard.com/article/international/daimler-ceo-says-apple-google-making-progress-on-car-116012501298_1.html
text : Daimler CEO says Apple, Google making progress on car

link : https://plus.google.com/+businessstandard/posts
text : Google+
```

#### DISCUSSION

The sample code below fetch only the first results page. If you need to fetch more results, extract the next link page (`#hpcontentbox div.next-colum > a`) and crawl it with Jsoup.

You'll notice there are additionnal parameters to the above link I provided you:

- `itemPerPages` : self explanatory (default to 19)
- `page`         : the search results page index (default is 1 if not provided)
- `company-code` : ?? (can be empty)

You may try to give `itemPerPages` to the url with larger values (100 or more). This may reduce your crawling time.

The `absUrl` method is used in order to have absolute urls instead of relative urls.